# Select count with nonaggregated columns

Tags: mysql, sql

With MySQL,I have a table where I need select the rows with diferents values in price column with your counting.

Table T1

| id | name | cat | col1 | col2 | ... | coln | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | cat1 | 1 | 1 | ... | 1 | 20 |
| 2 | A | cat1 | 1 | 1 | ... | 1 | 20 |
| 3 | A | cat1 | 1 | 1 | ... | 1 | 20 |
| 4 | A | cat1 | 1 | 1 | ... | 1 | 10 |
| 5 | A | cat1 | 1 | 1 | ... | 1 | 20 |
| 6 | A | cat1 | 1 | 1 | ... | 1 | 20 |
| 7 | A | cat1 | 1 | 1 | ... | 1 | 20 |

I need a result set as:

| id | name | cat | col1 | col2 | ... | coln | price | rowcount_with_same_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | cat1 | 1 | 1 | ... | 1 | 20 | 6 |
| 4 | A | cat1 | 1 | 1 | ... | 1 | 10 | 1 |

I have used something as:

```
select  price,T1.*,count(*) as count_of_rows_with_same_prices
from T1
group by 1;
```

But, I need disable "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY" because a have nonaggreated columns in my select list.

How can I do that  without disable "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY"?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and don't disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY.

Comment: Why do you "need" `1` and `4`? What's so special about them? Why not `6` and `4`? The question is sketchy.

Comment: @The Impaler No problem with 6 and 4. The important is take the rows and your counting to same prices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually you could use a query like below

```
SELECT 
id,name,cat, price,  count_of_rows_with_same_prices
from 
(
SELECT *, count(id) over (partition by price) as count_of_rows_with_same_prices, 
row_number() over (partition by price order by id asc) as r
from T1
)T 
where r=1
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. I have two responses working.

Answer (score 1):

First you want to get the count of entries by price, so write that out:

```
 SELECT price, count(*) as rc FROM T1 GROUP BY price
```

Next you can use that as a subquery in your query:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.cat, t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.coln, t1.price, t2.rc
FROM T1 t1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT price, count(*) as rc FROM T1 GROUP BY price) t2
        ON t1.price = t2.price
WHERE id in (1,4)
```

If you are on a newer version of mysql that supports window function you could also do something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (
       SELECT id, name, cat, col1, col2, coln, price
           ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY price) as count_of_rows_with_same_prices
       FROM T1
    )
WHERE id in (1, 4)
```

Also, don't disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY. That thing is set to TRUE for a reason. You will only write broken incorrect SQL when you turn it off and your problem still won't be solved.

Comment: Sorry, but I  can´t know the ids in (1,4). They are dynamics and generated when new records are added. The ids can not hard coded into sql query

Comment: I only added that as an example. You didn't explain why 1 and 4 are the only records coming through. Either way these should work for you.

Comment: I didn´t understand when you use  "where id in (x, y)".   I can't know theses ids. These ids are the ids of the grouped prices. And I don´t know what are them.

Comment: Then you could/should get those in the query using `MIN(id) OVER (PARTITTION BY PRICE ORDER BY id) as lowest_id_per_price`

Comment: or, a better option, add a rownumber, like: `row_number() over (partition by price order by id) as rownumber). then you can filter on rownumber=1.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with two window functions:

- `MIN`, working on the id
- `COUNT`, working on the price

Here's the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    MIN(id) OVER(
        PARTITION BY name, cat, price 
        ORDER BY price
    )                   AS id,
    name,
    cat,
    col1,
    col2,

    ....

    colN,
    COUNT(price) OVER(
        PARTITION BY name, cat, price 
        ORDER BY price
    )                   AS count_of_rows_with_same_prices
FROM 
    tab_t1
ORDER BY 
    id
```

You can find an SQL fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4kmJkjHkybMy8WtEJCbpfD/0).

Comment: Thank you. It works. I have two responses working.